# How to use MailKit with OAuth?

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, gmail, google-oauth

I'm writing a desktop application that can access GMail via IMAP. But I'm not sure if I implemented OAuth correctly.

MailKit says I should use a Service Account (https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#GMailOAuth2)

**But** Google says a Service Account should only be used if a Service wants to access it's own data, not the data of the user. Also I don't know how a different user can login in my application then.

I also found this tutorial and it's working for me (https://www.limilabs.com/blog/oauth2-gmail-imap-installed-applications)

**But** I don't know if it's a good practice. I can't hide the "ClientSecret" if I want do deploy my application. How to solve this? Also the user has to copy the auth key manually from the browser into the application.

Can someone suggest a quick, but state of the art solution? I'd like to build a Mail application and not an Oauth application ):